# Tuple from multiple values in a list

Tags: python, list, tuples

How can I make multiple tuples from the first element with each of the values in the corresponding list?

desired outcome: [(0,727), (0,1), (0,766), (0,950)... ]

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A nested comprehension will work:

```
data = [(0, [727, 1, ...]), (1, [...]), ...]

tpls = [(x, y) for x, lst in data for y in lst]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.product` which creates pairwise non-repeating combinations between two iterables.

```
from itertools import product

s_value = [[727, 1, 766], [989, 1067, 895], [21, 22, 23]]
c_keys = range(0, 3)

for c_key, s_val in zip(c_keys, s_value):
    print(list(product([c_key], s_val)))
     
>> [(0, 727), (0, 1), (0, 766)]
>> [(1, 989), (1, 1067), (1, 895)]
>> [(2, 21), (2, 22), (2, 23)]
```

If you want to create one big list with all combination tuples. You could add the `flatten` function of `more-itertools`

```
from more_itertools import flatten
from itertools import product

combs = [list(product([c_key], s_val)) for c_key, s_val in zip(c_keys, s_value)]
print(combs)
>> [[(0, 727), (0, 1), (0, 766)], [(1, 989), (1, 1067), (1, 895)], [(2, 21), (2, 22), (2, 23)]]

all_combs = list(flatten(combs))
print(all_combs)
>> [(0, 727), (0, 1), (0, 766), (1, 989), (1, 1067), (1, 895), (2, 21), (2, 22), (2, 23)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this...

```
lst = [(0,[0,1,2,3,4]),
        (1,[5,6,7,8,9])]

for key, value in lst:
    lst1 = [key] * len(value) # has a list of key repeated n times
    print(list(zip(lst1,value)))
```

output

```
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4)]
[(1, 5), (1, 6), (1, 7), (1, 8), (1, 9)]
```